# Unable to use methods from Domain Service class in WCF Ria?

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to build an silverlight application which takes user first name, last name, pass, email address in text boxes and then add these to the database.

For this i am using `WCF Ria Services`.

Steps i have followed are :

Added `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` and then `Domain Service class` in my project (in web part).

Now i have got some predefined methods in my DomainService Class like Insert, Update methods.  I know how to show data in `DataGrid` but its not what i want.

What i want is to customize all this for :

**When user clicks the submit button then there should be method inside this like `AddInfo(all parameters)` which can add all the data to my sql server database {at present LocalHost}.**

In simple words *accessing your database through custom methods to add data in sql server using WCF Ria Services*

I know it was very simple while working in .net forms and all. But how about Silverlight  & WCF ria ?

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In simple words accessing your database through custom methods to add
>   data in sql server using WCF Ria Services

What you should do is write a custom method in server-side.

On server-side, you have a `DomainService` class that should inherit from [`LinqToEntitiesDomainService<TContext>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423019%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).

Simply add a method in this class with the `Invoke` attribute, for example:

```
[Invoke]
public void AddNewUser(string name, string firstName, int age)
{
    // Put logic here to add the user to the DB
}
```

The logic to add a user to the database is really simple, just create a new `Entity`, add it to the context and call `context.SubmitChanges();`

When you compile the client RIA Services project, the auto-generated proxy class that correspond to your `DomainService` will contain your new method, and you'll be able to call it using:

```
yourDomainContext ctx = new yourDomainContext();
ctx.AddNewUser("dsd", "ds", 42).Completed += (sender, e) =>
{
     // Called asynchronously when the job is done
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the Insert method on your Domain Service, you should be able to call from the client:

```
//add your new data to the context
MyDomainServiceContext.Entity.Add(myEntity); //(where "Entity" is your entity Type)
//send all the changes to the server
MyDomainServiceContext.SubmitChanges();
```