# Who to create a custom method for data insert operation in silverlight?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am using silverlight WCF Ria service to handle database related operations in my application.

I do have a table

```
Post(Id int identity,Title varchar(50), Content varchar(50), Date datetime, Comments varchar(50) );
```

I can easily use

```
public void InsertPost( Post post )

{
if ((post.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(post, EntityState.Added);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Posts.AddObject(post);
            }
}
```

I can use this to update database but for that i need to pass all the entries i.e Id, Content etc

I need one other method through which i can skip passing `Id` values.
I want this method other than `InsertPost` method and how can i use that in my `submitbutton_click` event.

Please help

Comment: Can you post the error you received? Are you converting string to date?

Comment: soory my question was wrong.. it have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a custom method for data insertion using RIA Services, this answer [might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293621/870604).

But remember that if `Comments`, `Content`, `datetime`...etc. are `nullable` in your database, then you could use the `InsertPost` without specifying them:

```
Post newPost = new Post { Title = "title" };
ctx.InsertPost(newPost);
```